# Изменить язык приложения Flutter по нажатию на кнопку в настройках

Tags: flutter, dart, multilanguage

У меня в приложении есть настройки, одна из настроек это сменить язык приложения, например сейчас приложение на русском языке, а по нажатию на кнопку "изменить язык" - приложение должно стать на английском языке. Так же у меня имеется большое количество страниц в приложении, которые все привязаны к main.dart и нужно чтобы язык менялся одновременно на всех страницах, привязанных к main.dart. Помогите, пожалуйста! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

В данный момент занимаюсь разработкой первого в моём опыте настоящего приложения на flutter. Переключение языков реализовывал сам.
Приложение построено по паттерну MVVM, правда, предполагаю, что костыльно :D
Использовал библиотеку `stacked`, она помогает реализовать реактивное изменение данных при работы с ViewModel.  `
Создал ViewModel (объект, управляющий логикой) для контроля языка.

```
 return ViewModelBuilder<AppLanguageViewModel>.reactive(
      viewModelBuilder: () => locator<AppLanguageViewModel>(),
      builder: (context, AppLanguageViewModel viewModel, _) => MaterialApp(locale: viewModel.currentLocale))
```

Реализация моего ViewModel:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:myapp/src/app/locator.dart';
import 'package:myapp/src/misc/enums/language_enum.dart';
import 'package:myapp/src/models/app/language_model.dart';
import 'package:myapp/src/services/app/app_language_service.dart';

class AppLanguageViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  AppLanguageViewModel();

  final AppLanguageService _service = locator<AppLanguageService>();

  AppLanguage get current => _service.getCurrent();

  Locale get currentLocale => Locale(current.value);

  void setLanguage(AppLanguage lang) {
    _service.setCurrent(lang);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Ну вот, далее, от этого же объекта viewModel в дочерних экранах вызываем callback переключения языка.

При вызове метода `setLanguage(AppLanguage lang)` в любой части приложения от этого же экземпляра объекта `AppLanguageViewModel` благодаря `ViewModelBuilder` произойдёт обновление данных, приложение будет уведомлено и оно обновится с новым параметром `MaterialApp(locale: viewModel.currentLocale)`

Comment: Добрый день! Большое спасибо за помощь! Подскажите, пожалуйста, ViewModel мы создаем в main.dart, если же все страницы приложения подключены к нему?

Comment: Как я привёл кусок кода, где используется `ViewModelBuilder`, там создаётся экземпляр viewModel, далее используется для передачи данных в `MaterialApp`.  Я так и не узнал, какой наиболее правильный способ передать этот объект в дочерние экраны, я передавал с помощью параметров в конструктор экранов. Есть и другой вариант, сделать глобальный доступ к этому экземпляру (Синглтон) и в нужном месте доставать его, чтобы вызывать метод setLanguage

Answer (score 0):

Берите flutter_localization
[Локализация flutter проекта](https://habr.com/ru/company/alconost/blog/584942/)

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).